# Актуальна ли сейчас такая фишка?

Tags: jquery, дизайн

| Делал свежий дизайн, с использованием jQuery, решил дать полную свободу юзеру, и замутил блок управления отображением сайта, увеличение шрифта, цветовые схемы, убираю сайдбар, фоновую картинку меняю. Но мне сказали, что это глупо и совсем не модно сейчас, это не актуально и никто не будет пользоваться блоком, главное простота, а не юзабилити. Блок выезжает из-за угла по событию hover и не мешает в принципе, единственная трудность - это редактировать каждую тему при каких-либо изменениях в основной. Идея пришла после прочтения [данной статьи](http://www.w3school.ru/blog/design-showcase/style-switchers-are-back-ideas-examples.html) За рубежём почему-то это не осуждают, и основным применением это пользуется именно в домашних страничках и дизайн студиях, чтобы "показать свою власть над стилем" =) Что скажете? | [image: Панель управления стилями сайта] |
| --- | --- |

Answer (score 1):

В такой фишке есть смысл на больших порталах, типа yandex, google, yahoo, которыми люди пользуются каждый день, и следовательно в настройке которых на свой вкус есть смысл. Но в любом случае это не должна быть какая-то выезжающая панель, а как максимум ссылка типа "Настроить внешний вид сайта".

Comment: По-моему именно в больших порталах, в особенности гугл, такая фишка вообще не уместна, стиль порталов которыми пользуются каждый день должен быть однородным и узноваемым, а давать пользователю "cSS свободу" не пристижно было бы для такого международного гиганта. А про Яндекс я молчу, мне кажется им пора уже менять дизайн.

Answer (score 1):

А какой смысл? По сути функциональности сайту это не добавляет (имхо, кастомизировать отображение сайта, действительно, вряд ли кто-то будет, так чисто попробовать раз).

А вот где бы это было действительно полезно, так это на специализированном портале с направлением в верстку, или дизайн, или еще куда. Когда появляется именно цель использования, отличная от "чтобы поиграться". Иначе это просто слишком перегруженные наворотами дизайн.

Зато как ваша личная фишка, этот блок мог бы иметь место! Только размером поменьше, или использованный для других целей (например, доступ к "быстрым настройкам" вашего сайта, но только не внешнего вида, хотя кое-что и здесь не исключено), имхо.

А еще я не понимал людей, которые везде кричат, что это не модно или глупо.

Comment: Эта фишка придумана для блога. Чтобы сделать его более читабельным.

Comment: Хм, а вот о блоге даже не подумал.
По-моему стоит делать, только надо как-то ненавязчиво и компактно. Для меня было бы удобно. имхо.

Answer (score 1):

считаю,что имеет смысл сделать изменение шрифта,для плоховидящих,и сброс всего твоего придуманного дизайна на "дефолтный минимализм",где черным по белому и без всяких свистелок и п..ок,например тебе нравится одна цветовая гамма,но есть люди у которых эти цвета либо совсем не воспринимаются ,так называемая - цветовая слепота,либо просто раздражает этот цвет.

Comment: Считаю что не имеет смысла. Надо делать нормальный дизайн и без лишних свистелок, если не умеете - вы убогий дизайнер. А правка пользователем тем тут не причем. К тому же stylebot давно дает такой функционал кому это действительно нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Просто эта панель — перебор.

Шрифт делается больше меньше нажатием **Ctrl**+**+** или колесико мыши, работает в любом браузере, и это то, что пользователь пойдет делать первым делом, а не искать панель. Так что лучше проверьте, что бы сайт скейлился нормально, и ничего никуда не вылазило.

На сайдбар вешается маленькая стрелочка в верхнем углу скрывающая и раскрывающая его как в картах google, и то, это нужно далеко не всегда.

Темы если и прикручивать, то это как правило небольшие цветовые схемы, перегружающие маленький кусочек стилей, типа: бекграунд шапки, цвет фона и линков. Все. Координально менять интерфейс ни в коем случае не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Бессмысленная фигня. Если вы не можете сделать нормальный дизайн к сайту - это вам минус. Давать юзеру его изменять это верх глупости. Максимум можно дать несколько тем на выбор. А так вы просто захламляете сайт лишним функционалом. Это все равно что в терминале сделать возможность слушать музыку через наушники.

Comment: А в чём отличие выбора тем, и выбора отображения одной темы разными цветами:? Опять же повторюсь, дизайн сайта должен быть однородным и узноваемым, позволять менять темы, это дать пользователю шанс забыть как выглядит ваш основной дизайн сайта. За рубежём (ссылка в 1 посте) это хорошо практикуется.
З.Ы. неприятно было слышать фразу верх глупости, я не за оскорблениями сюда пришёл, а за ответом и советом.

Comment: Это прискорбно что вы не способны воспринимать критику в свой адрес когда спрашиваете насколько хороша ваша идея. 1-3 дизайна на выбор дают пользователю выбирать более удобный из них, в то же время вы не даете ему делать фигню из вашего сайта тем самым самостоятельно портить от него ощущения.

Answer (score -1):

Не слушайте никого, делайте эту фишку, но не как основную в вашем сайте. Очень маленькую и незаметную, и никогда не делайте ее выезжающей откуда-то, а то это смотрится как реклама.

Если очень хочется - сделайте одну кнопочку маленькую, а в самом разделе можно даже так сделать:

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/